# Issue with zxing QRCode Scanner ( ZXing library) in android

Tags: java, android, performance, qr-code, zxing

I am having trouble with zxing QRcode scanner.

The version i am using is`me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9`.

I am getting the  following error in my console:

```
E/CameraPreview: java.lang.RuntimeException: cancelAutoFocus failed
  java.lang.RuntimeException: cancelAutoFocus failed
  at android.hardware.Camera.native_cancelAutoFocus(Native Method)
  at android.hardware.Camera.cancelAutoFocus(Camera.java:1302)
  at me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.CameraPreview.stopCameraPreview(CameraPreview.java:115)
  at me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.CameraPreview.surfaceDestroyed(CameraPreview.java:74)
  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:566)
  at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:239)
  at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:14567)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout(ViewGroup.java:4792)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.removeAllViews(ViewGroup.java:4738)
  at me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.BarcodeScannerView.setupLayout(BarcodeScannerView.java:43)
  at me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.BarcodeScannerView.setupCameraPreview(BarcodeScannerView.java:87)
  at me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.CameraHandlerThread$1$1.run(CameraHandlerThread.java:31)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: I suggest you use Google's new library: https://developers.google.com/vision/

Comment: Please include your code, or rather, a minimum subset showing the error.

Comment: @Rissmon Suresh are you to find the solution for this

Comment: No. Can you try google vision API